# How to display & parse an image from rss feed to a html site using jquery, ajax and xml?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, rss

I was wondering if you guys could help me out on what's wrong with my code. So i'm trying to get a picture from rss feed to show up, but so far i only get [object] in the output div. I can't get any errors to show up in console either. any ideas? url and title show up as expected

Here's my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

   let getNewsBtn = $("#get-news-btn");
   let HsResultOutput = $("#content-output-fin");
   let HsUrl = 
   "https://www.hs.fi/rss/tuoreimmat.xml"

   getNewsBtn.on("click", getHs);

   function getHs(){
   $.ajax(
   {
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    url: HsUrl,        
   })
   .done(function(xml)     
   {                
    $.each($("item", xml), function(i, e) {

        var itemURL = ($(e).find("link"));
        var newsURL = "<a href='" + itemURL.text() + "'>" + 
        itemURL.text() +"</a>"

        var imgURL = ($(e).find("image"));
        var newsImg = "<p>" + imgURL.text(["image"]) + "</p>";

        var itemTitle = ($(e).find("title"));
        var newsTitle = "<h4>" + itemTitle.text() + "</h4>";

        $("#content-output-fin").append(newsURL);
        $("#content-output-fin").append(newsImg);
        $("#content-output-fin").append(newsTitle);

        });
        });
        };
        });

        HTML: <h4 class="modal-title" id="content-output-hs"></h4>
```

Comment: You have the html enclosed in backticks change to single quotes `htmlTxt +=  ' ... '`

Comment: @ArleighHix ty for the answer, got it figured out in a slighly different way(see updated code). Now the only problem i have is the image :)